# How to use an object of type class from an generic class as a parameter? - generics and reflection combined

Tags: java, generics, reflection, parameters, constructor

I have two classes:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractSuperClass<A, B> {

    public MyAbstractSuperClass(Class<A> a, Class<B> b) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}

public class MyClass<A> extends MyAbstractSuperClass<A, MyOtherClass<A>> {

    public MyClass(Class<A> a) {
    super(a, MyOtherClass.class));
            ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Now you see, the subclass has to call the superclass's constructor. At that line I get the following error:

```
The constructor MySuperClass<A, MyOtherClass<A>>(Class<A>, Class<MyOtherClass>) is undefined
```

- So how do I get an object of type `Class<MyOtherClass<A>>`?
- And how do I do it in the super constructor call, where I can't execute much?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no class `MySuperClass` as referenced in the error message.  Is that error supposed to read: `The constructor MyAbstractSuperClass< ...`

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is expecting a `Class<MyOtherClass<A>>`, not a `Class<MyOtherClass>`.  The only way I can think to satisfy the compiler is through an ugly series of casts:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
public MyClass(Class<A> a) {
   super(a, (Class<MyOtherClass<A>>)(Class<?>)MyOtherClass.class);
}
```

It is type safe as seen through inspection, since the class literal for the raw type `MyOtherClass` is the same as for the parameterized `MyOtherClass<A>`.  But that doesn't stop an unchecked warning from being generated, which can be suppressed as above, or simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the type parameter of `MyOtherClass` in the `MyClass` definition. You're apparently not interested in this anywhere in `MyClass`' body.

```
public class MyClass<A> extends MyAbstractSuperClass<A, MyOtherClass> {
    public MyClass(Class<A> a) {
       super(a, MyOtherClass.class);
    }
}
```

Add a `@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")` if the warning bothers you.

Answer (score -1):

You must add a second argument to the `MyClass` constructor:

```
public MyClass(Class<A> a, Class<MyOtherClass<A>> bClass) {
    super(a, bclass));
}
```

@Bert F: This does "pass the buck" in some sense, but it passes the buck to someone who can actually provide a class literal of the appropriate type.  The caller knows the actual value of the type variable `A`, and so can provide a class literal of the correct type.  Due to erasure, `MyClass` can't do that.

Comment: Doesn't this just pass the buck? Wouldn't the code that tries to instantiate `MyClass` now have the same problem that `MyClass` had before - it can't create a class literal of a concrete parameterized type?